# Install Perl Math::GMP on OSX

Tags: macos, perl, gmp

I am attempting to install the Perl package Math::GMP on OS X El Capitan.

I had one computer where this worked without issue - but a second computer is running into the following problem:

The Perl module Math::GMP requires the C library for GMP, so I have done a `brew install gmp`

This installed GMP including the following file:

```
/usr/local/include/gmp.h
```

But the package install still fails claiming I don't have gmp installed:

```
$ sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[1]> install Math::GMP
Reading '/Users/chaosadmin/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Sat, 14 Nov 2015 09:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Math::GMP'
Checksum for /Users/me/.cpan/sources/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/Math-GMP-2.11.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /Users/me/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring S/SH/SHLOMIF/Math-GMP-2.11.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Can't link/include C library 'gmp.h', 'gmp', aborting.
No 'Makefile' created  SHLOMIF/Math-GMP-2.11.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 SHLOMIF/Math-GMP-2.11.tar.gz                 : writemakefile NO -- No 'Makefile' created
```

The obvious line is:
`Can't link/include C library 'gmp.h', 'gmp', aborting.`

But I definitely have "gmp.h" installed in `/usr/local/include/gmp.h`
I'm unsure why it's failing to install on this OS X El Capitan machine (it worked fine on my other one).

In the CPAN shell I used:

```
look Math::GMP
```

And updated the Makefile.PL to debug:

```
check_lib_or_exit(
    header => 'gmp.h',
    lib => 'gmp',
    debug => 'true'
);
```

Which displayed the following error when running `perl Makefile.PL`

```
# /usr/bin/cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -fstack-protector assertlibD4RJzZEa.c -o assertlibwGFzIVsM
assertlibD4RJzZEa.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found
#include <gmp.h>
```

Comment: Most likely, /usr/local isn't in the default list of places the compiler looks for stuff in. Use the `look` function at the cpan prompt to get a shell with the unpacked module, and see if the documentation says anything about giving switches to `Makefile.PL` to tell it where it can find gmp.

Comment: Okay - I was able to add 'debug' 'true' for the line that's failing in Makefile.PL - but still not fixing it for me.

Comment: Nothing in the INSTALL or README about how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this, I was able to get Math::BigInt::GMP to install on Sonoma 14.1.2 by doing the following:

```
brew install gmp

# possibly ADD TO ~/.bashrc, can export from cmd line

export CPATH=/opt/homebrew/include:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CPATH=`xcrun --show-sdk-path`/opt/homebrew/include:$CPATH
```

This also solved some related install resolution issues I had with openssl and some other packages. I sourced this somewhere some time ago and had documented it. When installing on a new Mac I dug up my notes. If I found the original source material, I'll update this zombified question again.

Answer (score -2):

On Centos :

Just install this : yum install gmp* -y

Good Luck :)

Comment: This seems irrelevant as the original question is about mac OS.